# Is shim a redundant package that is never used, compared to shim-signed?

Tags: apt, grub2, 20.04, package-management, uefi

I did `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` to free up some space, however it also removed the latest `shim` package that got updated just today.

```
shim (15.4-0ubuntu7)
```

also updated today was

```
shim-signed (15.4-0ubuntu7)
```

but `shim-signed` was NOT removed.

If `autoremove` removes older versions no longer required, however I believe `shim` is an essential element for secure boot process, or is it not? Please help me understand why it got removed.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the files in `shim` have been moved to `shim-signed` and that probably makes `shim` no longer necessary.

The [file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/shim/filelist) from the original `shim` version shipped with focal (`15+1533136590.3beb971-0ubuntu1`)

```
/usr/lib/shim/BOOTX64.CSV
/usr/lib/shim/fbx64.efi
/usr/lib/shim/mmx64.efi
/usr/lib/shim/shimx64.efi
/usr/share/doc/shim/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/shim/copyright
```

The [file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/amd64/shim/filelist) from the current `shim` version in focal-updates (`15.4-0ubuntu7`)

```
/usr/share/doc/shim/buildinfo_amd64.gz
/usr/share/doc/shim/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/shim/copyright
```

The [file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/shim-signed/filelist) from the original `shim-signed` version shipped with focal (`1.40.3+15+1533136590.3beb971-0ubuntu1`)

```
/usr/lib/shim/mok/openssl.cnf
/usr/lib/shim/shimx64.efi.signed
/usr/sbin/update-secureboot-policy
/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/source_shim-signed.py
/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/source_shim.py
/usr/share/doc/shim-signed/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/shim-signed/copyright
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/shim-signed
```

The [file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/amd64/shim-signed/filelist) from the current `shim-signed` version in focal-updates (`1.40.6+15.4-0ubuntu7`)

```
/usr/lib/shim/BOOTX64.CSV
/usr/lib/shim/fbx64.efi
/usr/lib/shim/mmx64.efi
/usr/lib/shim/mok/openssl.cnf
/usr/lib/shim/shimx64.efi
/usr/lib/shim/shimx64.efi.dualsigned
/usr/lib/shim/shimx64.efi.signed
/usr/sbin/update-secureboot-policy
/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/source_shim-signed.py
/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/source_shim.py
/usr/share/doc/shim-signed/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/shim-signed/copyright
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/shim-signed
```

It appears these files are now part of `shim-signed` and that `shim` no longer provides anything critical

```
/usr/lib/shim/BOOTX64.CSV
/usr/lib/shim/fbx64.efi
/usr/lib/shim/mmx64.efi
/usr/lib/shim/shimx64.efi
```

The reason for the change appears to be the new upstream 15.4 release and is [tracked in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shim/+bug/1921134).  In particular, the changelog notes

```
    - Update packaging to pull fb and mm from shim-signed package as in
      later releases, dropping the runtime dependency on shim.
```

Comment: What I read was `shim` allowed the source code to be verified so binaries could be fully reproducible, now that files have been moved into `shim-signed` itself, can the code still be verifiable?